# XML not getting outputted : XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: xml, .htaccess

```
<?php
 header('Content-type: application/xml');
 echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>";
 require_once('includes/pdo_connection.php');
 $query = "Select * from photo_category WHERE status='A'";
 $result = DB::instance()->prepare($query)->execute()->fetchAll();
 $output="<juiceboxgallery galleryTitle='FutureFit Gallery'>";
 foreach($result as $row){
 $cat_id = $row['id'];
 $cat_name = $row['photo_category_name'];
 $query2 = "Select * from photogallery WHERE pcID = '$cat_id' AND status = 'A' order 
 by id desc";

$result2 = DB::instance()->prepare($query2)->execute()->fetchAll();
foreach($result2 as $row2){
$imgCaption = $row2['img_label'];
$thumb = $row2['thumb_img'];
$large = $row2['photo_gallery_image'];
$output .= "<image imageURL='images/photogallery/large/$large'
thumbURL='images/photogallery/thumb/$thumb'
linkURL='' linkTarget='_blank'> <title>".$imgCaption."</title></image>";
}
}
$output .= "</juiceboxgallery>"; ?>
<?php echo $output; ?>
```

And in `.htaccess' i have handeled like this

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.xml$">
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
 </IfModule>
```

When i run this XML then i get error like in FF as:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Line Number 5, Column 11:
$query = "Select * from photo_category WHERE status='A'";
```

Please help me format it properly. I am stuck with my work here. I am embedding PHP in XML files. And file extension is `.xml` and it is working fine at `localhost` ::(

Comment: Did you forget the `</IfModule>` tag ? That would explain the XML not being well-formed.

Comment: nops.. t is there.. i forgot to paste here.. now pasted

Comment: Are there any special characters like `&` in `$imgCaption`?

Comment: No.. There are only chatacters like Zumba and one of them is Cirtcuit training .. no special characters